# Remove opacity from image but keep for background

Tags: html, css

What im trying to do is display a block `header-wrapper` that has background opacity. This block contains a image and text. Also i have used `background-size: cover;` for a responsive image background.

My problem is I only want the block `header-wrapper` background to be opaque but the image too is getting an opaque display. How can this be removed, there have been similar questions asked here related but only concern with the text not been opaque.

**HTML**

```
<section>

    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <p><img src="http://dev3.rezg.net/rezbase_v3Reservations/external-bec/template5/images/flights-hover.png"/></p>
        <p>Title 1</p>
    </div>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    background:url(https://aimlessblonde.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/ab-2.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;    
}

.header-wrapper{
    background:rgba(224,74,73,0.99); 
    padding:5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px; color:#fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.header-wrapper > p{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Example on what im working : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shanaka/u2zy63k4/)

Comment: You already have done it? `background:rgba(224,74,73,0.99); ` that 99 is the Alpha. Change that to 60 or something  and remove `opacity` and it will change the opacity for the background only.

Comment: Add `opacity: 1.0 !important;` to the image

Comment: @Pugazh [Do not use !important](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got a little confused.

Remove `opacity` from `.header-wrapper` and just change the alpha on your background from 99 to 60 (or whatever you want).

```
background:rgba(224,74,73,0.60); //this last number is the alpha, has been changed from 90 to 60
```

Please [**look here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()) to learn a little more about rgba.

Below I have made the changes to show you how it now looks.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://aimlessblonde.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/ab-2.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.header-wrapper {
  background: rgba(224, 74, 73, 0.60);
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.header-wrapper > p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <p>
      <img src="http://www.wellclean.com/wp-content/themes/artgallery_3.0/images/car3.png" />
    </p>
    <p>Title 1</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: yes your right i added opacity to block as well that causes the opacity to child elements.

Comment: @Shanaka Correct, the opacity will affect all children.

Answer (score 4):

You can give following way. Don't give direct `opacity: 0.8;` to div give opacity to background `rgba(224, 74, 73, 0.8);`

```
.header-wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(224, 74, 73, 0.8);
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/u2zy63k4/1/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Beat me to it. `opacity: X` makes the whole element, including descendants be transperent. Whereas setting an opacitiy on the background color itself will just make that color transparent. Note that semi-transparent colors are not supported in IE8 and some other browsers, but there is an easy fallback: https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
.header-wrapper{
    background:rgba(224,74,73,0.80); 
    padding:5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px; color:#fff;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Is this you want to achieve??? Let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the background translucent, just apply that alpha to the color itself:

```
.header-wrapper{
    background:rgba(224,74,73,0.8); /* 0.99 -> 0.8 */ 
    padding:5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px; color:#fff;
    /* opacity: 0.8; */ /* rid of opacity */
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```